# java POI PowerPoint need x y coordinates for an image

Tags: java, apache-poi

trying to do a mock-up of a powerpoint that was created and trying to place images using poi

Im doing this :

```
pict2.setAnchor(new java.awt.Rectangle(100, 100, 300, 200));
```

= = Recangle(x-corrdinate,y-coordinate,width, height);

on the original powerpoint I can right click on an image and get position and size...how can I translate this to pixels??

[image]

Comment: I just multiplied the values by 72

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I just multiplied the values by 72